# angularjs ng options with condition based on another ng model

Tags: angularjs

I have to filter the ng options with a nested property of the object. here is my code

```html
<select ng-model="clas.department" ng-options="department as department.name for department in departments  | filter:{department.course.id : clas.course.id}: true">
  <option value="">Select Department</option>
</select>
```

where `clas.course.id` is another ng model.

i am getting this error:

`angular.js:12477 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=34&p3=departments%20%20%7CNaNilter%3A%7Bdepartment.course.id%20%3A%clas.course.id%7D%3A%20true&p4=.course.id%20%3A%clas.course.id%7D%3A%20true
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Object.throwError (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:209:339)
    at Object.consume (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:210:9)
    at Object.object (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:209:171)
    at Object.primary (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:206:151)
    at Object.unary (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:205:503)
    at Object.multiplicative (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:205:249)
    at Object.additive (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:205:76)
    at Object.relational (http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:204:416)`

Comment: Please share the `department` and `clas` JSON data

Comment: for department `{"id":1,"objectVersion":0,"name":"CSE","enable":true,"course":{"id":1,"objectVersion":0,"name":"B.Tech","enable":true}}` and clas `{"id":1,"objectVersion":0,"name":"B.Tech","enable":true}`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be such a thing as `clas.course.id`. Try `clas.id` instead.

Comment: clas.course is my ng model based on this ng model i have to filter

Comment: what are you trying to do with this statement  filter:{department.course.id : clas.course.id: true?

Comment: checking both id s are same

Comment: In the snippet a curly brace is missing after `clas.course.id` - did you include that in your code?

Comment: What's the functionality or you can say what you want to achieve by this code ?

Comment: i want to check `departanment.course.id and clas.course.id` are same

Comment: I must say you will be getting some error in console. can you paste it here ?

Comment: Post the values of 'departments' and 'clas' JSON data. Seems like above provided JSON data is incorrect.

Comment: its the same angular dont support nested notations in its filters?[link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/531)